# How can i decrypt MD5 hash in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3, md5

**How can i decrypt MD5 hash in ActionScript ?**

that is flash game, i want learn decrypt md5 in flash game. thanks..

image:
http ://b1302.hizliresim.com/16/8/jwu73.jpg

and How can i solve base64 and sha1 codes ?

```
    package com
{

    public class MD5 extends Object
    {
        public static const HEX_FORMAT_LOWERCASE:uint = 0;
        public static const HEX_FORMAT_UPPERCASE:uint = 1;
        public static const BASE64_PAD_CHARACTER_DEFAULT_COMPLIANCE:String = "";
        public static const BASE64_PAD_CHARACTER_RFC_COMPLIANCE:String = "=";
        public static var hexcase:uint = 0;
        public static var b64pad:String = "";

        public function MD5()
        {
            return;
        }// end function

        public static function encrypt(param1:String) : String
        {
            return hex_md5(param1);
        }// end function

        public static function hex_md5(param1:String) : String
        {
            return rstr2hex(rstr_md5(str2rstr_utf8(param1)));
        }// end function

        public static function b64_md5(param1:String) : String
        {
            return rstr2b64(rstr_md5(str2rstr_utf8(param1)));
        }// end function

        public static function any_md5(param1:String, param2:String) : String
        {
            return rstr2any(rstr_md5(str2rstr_utf8(param1)), param2);
        }// end function

        public static function hex_hmac_md5(param1:String, param2:String) : String
        {
            return rstr2hex(rstr_hmac_md5(str2rstr_utf8(param1), str2rstr_utf8(param2)));
        }// end function

        public static function b64_hmac_md5(param1:String, param2:String) : String
        {
            return rstr2b64(rstr_hmac_md5(str2rstr_utf8(param1), str2rstr_utf8(param2)));
        }// end function

        public static function any_hmac_md5(param1:String, param2:String, param3:String) : String
        {
            return rstr2any(rstr_hmac_md5(str2rstr_utf8(param1), str2rstr_utf8(param2)), param3);
        }// end function

        public static function md5_vm_test() : Boolean
        {
            return hex_md5("abc") == "900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72";
        }// end function

        public static function rstr_md5(param1:String) : String
        {
            return binl2rstr(binl_md5(rstr2binl(param1), param1.length * 8));
        }// end function

        public static function rstr_hmac_md5(param1:String, param2:String) : String
        {
            var _loc_3:* = rstr2binl(param1);
            if (_loc_3.length > 16)
            {
                _loc_3 = binl_md5(_loc_3, param1.length * 8);
            }
            var _loc_4:* = new Array(16);
            var _loc_5:* = new Array(16);
            var _loc_6:* = 0;
            while (_loc_6 < 16)
            {

                _loc_4[_loc_6] = _loc_3[_loc_6] ^ 909522486;
                _loc_5[_loc_6] = _loc_3[_loc_6] ^ 1549556828;
                _loc_6 = _loc_6 + 1;
            }
            var _loc_7:* = binl_md5(_loc_4.concat(rstr2binl(param2)), 512 + param2.length * 8);
            return binl2rstr(binl_md5(_loc_5.concat(_loc_7), 512 + 128));
        }// end function

        public static function rstr2hex(param1:String) : String
        {
            var _loc_4:* = NaN;
            var _loc_2:* = hexcase ? ("0123456789ABCDEF") : ("0123456789abcdef");
            var _loc_3:* = "";
            var _loc_5:* = 0;
            while (_loc_5 < param1.length)
            {

                _loc_4 = param1.charCodeAt(_loc_5);
                _loc_3 = _loc_3 + (_loc_2.charAt(_loc_4 >>> 4 & 15) + _loc_2.charAt(_loc_4 & 15));
                _loc_5 = _loc_5 + 1;
            }
            return _loc_3;
        }// end function

        public static function rstr2b64(param1:String) : String
        {
            var _loc_6:* = undefined;
            var _loc_7:* = NaN;
            var _loc_2:* = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
            var _loc_3:* = "";
            var _loc_4:* = param1.length;
            var _loc_5:* = 0;
            while (_loc_5 < _loc_4)
            {

                _loc_6 = param1.charCodeAt(_loc_5) << 16 | ((_loc_5 + 1) < _loc_4 ? (param1.charCodeAt((_loc_5 + 1)) << 8) : (0)) | (_loc_5 + 2 < _loc_4 ? (param1.charCodeAt(_loc_5 + 2)) : (0));
                _loc_7 = 0;
                while (_loc_7 < 4)
                {

                    if (_loc_5 * 8 + _loc_7 * 6 > param1.length * 8)
                    {
                        _loc_3 = _loc_3 + b64pad;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _loc_3 = _loc_3 + _loc_2.charAt(_loc_6 >>> 6 * (3 - _loc_7) & 63);
                    }
                    _loc_7 = _loc_7 + 1;
                }
                _loc_5 = _loc_5 + 3;
            }
            return _loc_3;
        }// end function

        public static function rstr2any(param1:String, param2:String) : String
        {
            var _loc_5:* = NaN;
            var _loc_6:* = NaN;
            var _loc_7:* = NaN;
            var _loc_8:* = null;
            var _loc_3:* = param2.length;
            var _loc_4:* = [];
            var _loc_9:* = new Array(param1.length / 2);
            _loc_5 = 0;
            while (_loc_5 < _loc_9.length)
            {

                _loc_9[_loc_5] = param1.charCodeAt(_loc_5 * 2) << 8 | param1.charCodeAt(_loc_5 * 2 + 1);
                _loc_5 = _loc_5 + 1;
            }
            while (_loc_9.length > 0)
            {

                _loc_8 = [];
                _loc_7 = 0;
                _loc_5 = 0;
                while (_loc_5 < _loc_9.length)
                {

                    _loc_7 = (_loc_7 << 16) + _loc_9[_loc_5];
                    _loc_6 = Math.floor(_loc_7 / _loc_3);
                    _loc_7 = _loc_7 - _loc_6 * _loc_3;
                    if (_loc_8.length > 0 || _loc_6 > 0)
                    {
                        _loc_8[_loc_8.length] = _loc_6;
                    }
                    _loc_5 = _loc_5 + 1;
                }
                _loc_4[_loc_4.length] = _loc_7;
                _loc_9 = _loc_8;
            }
            var _loc_10:* = "";
            _loc_5 = _loc_4.length - 1;
            while (_loc_5 >= 0)
            {

                _loc_10 = _loc_10 + param2.charAt(_loc_4[_loc_5]);
                _loc_5 = _loc_5 - 1;
            }
            return _loc_10;
        }// end function

        public static function str2rstr_utf8(param1:String) : String
        {
            var _loc_4:* = NaN;
            var _loc_5:* = NaN;
            var _loc_2:* = "";
            var _loc_3:* = -1;
            while (++_loc_3 < param1.length)
            {

                _loc_4 = param1.charCodeAt(_loc_3);
                _loc_5 = (_loc_3 + 1) < param1.length ? (param1.charCodeAt((_loc_3 + 1))) : (0);
                if (_loc_4 >= 55296 && _loc_4 <= 56319 && _loc_5 >= 56320 && _loc_5 <= 57343)
                {
                    _loc_4 = 65536 + ((_loc_4 & 1023) << 10) + (_loc_5 & 1023);
                    _loc_3 = _loc_3 + 1;
                }
                if (_loc_4 <= 127)
                {
                    _loc_2 = _loc_2 + String.fromCharCode(_loc_4);
                    continue;
                }
                if (_loc_4 <= 2047)
                {
                    _loc_2 = _loc_2 + String.fromCharCode(192 | _loc_4 >>> 6 & 31, 128 | _loc_4 & 63);
                    continue;
                }
                if (_loc_4 <= 65535)
                {
                    _loc_2 = _loc_2 + String.fromCharCode(224 | _loc_4 >>> 12 & 15, 128 | _loc_4 >>> 6 & 63, 128 | _loc_4 & 63);
                    continue;
                }
                if (_loc_4 <= 2097151)
                {
                    _loc_2 = _loc_2 + String.fromCharCode(240 | _loc_4 >>> 18 & 7, 128 | _loc_4 >>> 12 & 63, 128 | _loc_4 >>> 6 & 63, 128 | _loc_4 & 63);
                }
            }
            return _loc_2;
        }// end function

        public static function str2rstr_utf16le(param1:String) : String
        {
            var _loc_2:* = "";
            var _loc_3:* = 0;
            while (_loc_3 < param1.length)
            {

                _loc_2 = _loc_2 + String.fromCharCode(param1.charCodeAt(_loc_3) & 255, param1.charCodeAt(_loc_3) >>> 8 & 255);
                _loc_3 = _loc_3 + 1;
            }
            return _loc_2;
        }// end function

        public static function str2rstr_utf16be(param1:String) : String
        {
            var _loc_2:* = "";
            var _loc_3:* = 0;
            while (_loc_3 < param1.length)
            {

                _loc_2 = _loc_2 + String.fromCharCode(param1.charCodeAt(_loc_3) >>> 8 & 255, param1.charCodeAt(_loc_3) & 255);
                _loc_3 = _loc_3 + 1;
            }
            return _loc_2;
        }// end function

        public static function rstr2binl(param1:String) : Array
        {
            var _loc_3:* = NaN;
            var _loc_2:* = new Array(param1.length >> 2);
            _loc_3 = 0;
            while (_loc_3 < _loc_2.length)
            {

                _loc_2[_loc_3] = 0;
                _loc_3 = _loc_3 + 1;
            }
            _loc_3 = 0;
            while (_loc_3 < param1.length * 8)
            {

                _loc_2[_loc_3 >> 5] = _loc_2[_loc_3 >> 5] | (param1.charCodeAt(_loc_3 / 8) & 255) << _loc_3 % 32;
                _loc_3 = _loc_3 + 8;
            }
            return _loc_2;
        }// end function

        public static function binl2rstr(param1:Array) : String
        {
            var _loc_2:* = "";
            var _loc_3:* = 0;
            while (_loc_3 < param1.length * 32)
            {

                _loc_2 = _loc_2 + String.fromCharCode(param1[_loc_3 >> 5] >>> _loc_3 % 32 & 255);
                _loc_3 = _loc_3 + 8;
            }
            return _loc_2;
        }// end function

        public static function binl_md5(param1:Array, param2:Number) : Array
        {
            var _loc_8:* = NaN;
            var _loc_9:* = NaN;
            var _loc_10:* = NaN;
            var _loc_11:* = NaN;
            param1[param2 >> 5] = param1[param2 >> 5] | 128 << param2 % 32;
            param1[(param2 + 64 >>> 9 << 4) + 14] = param2;
            var _loc_3:* = 1732584193;
            var _loc_4:* = -271733879;
            var _loc_5:* = -1732584194;
            var _loc_6:* = 271733878;
            var _loc_7:* = 0;
            while (_loc_7 < param1.length)
            {

                _loc_8 = _loc_3;
                _loc_9 = _loc_4;
                _loc_10 = _loc_5;
                _loc_11 = _loc_6;
                _loc_3 = md5_ff(_loc_3, _loc_4, _loc_5, _loc_6, param1[_loc_7 + 0], 7, -680876936);
                _loc_6 = md5_ff(_loc_6, _loc_3, _loc_4, _loc_5, param1[(_loc_7 + 1)], 12, -389564586);
                _loc_5 = md5_ff(_loc_5, _loc_6, _loc_3, _loc_4, param1[_loc_7 + 2], 17, 606105819);
                _loc_4 = md5_ff(_loc_4, _loc_5, _loc_6, _loc_3, param1[_loc_7 + 3], 22, -1044525330);
                _loc_3 = md5_ff(_loc_3, _loc_4, _loc_5, _loc_6, param1[_loc_7 + 4], 7, -176418897);
                _loc_6 = md5_ff(_loc_6, _loc_3, _loc_4, _loc_5, param1[_loc_7 + 5], 12, 1200080426);
                _loc_5 = md5_ff(_loc_5, _loc_6, _loc_3, _loc_4, param1[_loc_7 + 6], 17, -1473231341);
                _loc_4 = md5_ff(_loc_4, _loc_5, _loc_6, _loc_3, param1[_loc_7 + 7], 22, -45705983);
                _loc_3 = md5_ff(_loc_3, _loc_4, _loc_5, _loc_6, param1[_loc_7 + 8], 7, 1770035416);
                _loc_6 = md5_ff(_loc_6, _loc_3, _loc_4, _loc_5, param1[_loc_7 + 9], 12, -1958414417);
                _loc_5 = md5_ff(_loc_5, _loc_6, _loc_3, _loc_4, param1[_loc_7 + 10], 17, -42063);
                _loc_4 = md5_ff(_loc_4, _loc_5, _loc_6, _loc_3, param1[_loc_7 + 11], 22, -1990404162);
                _loc_3 = md5_ff(_loc_3, _loc_4, _loc_5, _loc_6, param1[_loc_7 + 12], 7, 1804603682);
                _loc_6 = md5_ff(_loc_6, _loc_3, _loc_4, _loc_5, param1[_loc_7 + 13], 12, -40341101);
                _loc_5 = md5_ff(_loc_5, _loc_6, _loc_3, _loc_4, param1[_loc_7 + 14], 17, -1502002290);
                _loc_4 = md5_ff(_loc_4, _loc_5, _loc_6, _loc_3, param1[_loc_7 + 15], 22, 1236535329);
                _loc_3 = md5_gg(_loc_3, _loc_4, _loc_5, _loc_6, param1[(_loc_7 + 1)], 5, -165796510);
                _loc_6 = md5_gg(_loc_6, _loc_3, _loc_4, _loc_5, param1[_loc_7 + 6], 9, -1069501632);
                _loc_5 = md5_gg(_loc_5, _loc_6, _loc_3, _loc_4, param1[_loc_7 + 11], 14, 643717713);
                _loc_4 = md5_gg(_loc_4, _loc_5, _loc_6, _loc_3, param1[_loc_7 + 0], 20, -373897302);
                _loc_3 = md5_gg(_loc_3, _loc_4, _loc_5, _loc_6, param1[_loc_7 + 5], 5, -701558691);
                _loc_6 = md5_gg(_loc_6, _loc_3, _loc_4, _loc_5, param1[_loc_7 + 10], 9, 38016083);
                _loc_5 = md5_gg(_loc_5, _loc_6, _loc_3, _loc_4, param1[_loc_7 + 15], 14, -660478335);
                _loc_4 = md5_gg(_loc_4, _loc_5, _loc_6, _loc_3, param1[_loc_7 + 4], 20, -405537848);
                _loc_3 = md5_gg(_loc_3, _loc_4, _loc_5, _loc_6, param1[_loc_7 + 9], 5, 568446438);
                _loc_6 = md5_gg(_loc_6, _loc_3, _loc_4, _loc_5, param1[_loc_7 + 14], 9, -1019803690);
                _loc_5 = md5_gg(_loc_5, _loc_6, _loc_3, _loc_4, param1[_loc_7 + 3], 14, -187363961);
                _loc_4 = md5_gg(_loc_4, _loc_5, _loc_6, _loc_3, param1[_loc_7 + 8], 20, 1163531501);
                _loc_3 = md5_gg(_loc_3, _loc_4, _loc_5, _loc_6, param1[_loc_7 + 13], 5, -1444681467);
                _loc_6 = md5_gg(_loc_6, _loc_3, _loc_4, _loc_5, param1[_loc_7 + 2], 9, -51403784);
                _loc_5 = md5_gg(_loc_5, _loc_6, _loc_3, _loc_4, param1[_loc_7 + 7], 14, 1735328473);
                _loc_4 = md5_gg(_loc_4, _loc_5, _loc_6, _loc_3, param1[_loc_7 + 12], 20, -1926607734);
                _loc_3 = md5_hh(_loc_3, _loc_4, _loc_5, _loc_6, param1[_loc_7 + 5], 4, -378558);
                _loc_6 = md5_hh(_loc_6, _loc_3, _loc_4, _loc_5, param1[_loc_7 + 8], 11, -2022574463);
                _loc_5 = md5_hh(_loc_5, _loc_6, _loc_3, _loc_4, param1[_loc_7 + 11], 16, 1839030562);
                _loc_4 = md5_hh(_loc_4, _loc_5, _loc_6, _loc_3, param1[_loc_7 + 14], 23, -35309556);
                _loc_3 = md5_hh(_loc_3, _loc_4, _loc_5, _loc_6, param1[(_loc_7 + 1)], 4, -1530992060);
                _loc_6 = md5_hh(_loc_6, _loc_3, _loc_4, _loc_5, param1[_loc_7 + 4], 11, 1272893353);
                _loc_5 = md5_hh(_loc_5, _loc_6, _loc_3, _loc_4, param1[_loc_7 + 7], 16, -155497632);
                _loc_4 = md5_hh(_loc_4, _loc_5, _loc_6, _loc_3, param1[_loc_7 + 10], 23, -1094730640);
                _loc_3 = md5_hh(_loc_3, _loc_4, _loc_5, _loc_6, param1[_loc_7 + 13], 4, 681279174);
                _loc_6 = md5_hh(_loc_6, _loc_3, _loc_4, _loc_5, param1[_loc_7 + 0], 11, -358537222);
                _loc_5 = md5_hh(_loc_5, _loc_6, _loc_3, _loc_4, param1[_loc_7 + 3], 16, -722521979);
                _loc_4 = md5_hh(_loc_4, _loc_5, _loc_6, _loc_3, param1[_loc_7 + 6], 23, 76029189);
                _loc_3 = md5_hh(_loc_3, _loc_4, _loc_5, _loc_6, param1[_loc_7 + 9], 4, -640364487);
                _loc_6 = md5_hh(_loc_6, _loc_3, _loc_4, _loc_5, param1[_loc_7 + 12], 11, -421815835);
                _loc_5 = md5_hh(_loc_5, _loc_6, _loc_3, _loc_4, param1[_loc_7 + 15], 16, 530742520);
                _loc_4 = md5_hh(_loc_4, _loc_5, _loc_6, _loc_3, param1[_loc_7 + 2], 23, -995338651);
                _loc_3 = md5_ii(_loc_3, _loc_4, _loc_5, _loc_6, param1[_loc_7 + 0], 6, -198630844);
                _loc_6 = md5_ii(_loc_6, _loc_3, _loc_4, _loc_5, param1[_loc_7 + 7], 10, 1126891415);
                _loc_5 = md5_ii(_loc_5, _loc_6, _loc_3, _loc_4, param1[_loc_7 + 14], 15, -1416354905);
                _loc_4 = md5_ii(_loc_4, _loc_5, _loc_6, _loc_3, param1[_loc_7 + 5], 21, -57434055);
                _loc_3 = md5_ii(_loc_3, _loc_4, _loc_5, _loc_6, param1[_loc_7 + 12], 6, 1700485571);
                _loc_6 = md5_ii(_loc_6, _loc_3, _loc_4, _loc_5, param1[_loc_7 + 3], 10, -1894986606);
                _loc_5 = md5_ii(_loc_5, _loc_6, _loc_3, _loc_4, param1[_loc_7 + 10], 15, -1051523);
                _loc_4 = md5_ii(_loc_4, _loc_5, _loc_6, _loc_3, param1[(_loc_7 + 1)], 21, -2054922799);
                _loc_3 = md5_ii(_loc_3, _loc_4, _loc_5, _loc_6, param1[_loc_7 + 8], 6, 1873313359);
                _loc_6 = md5_ii(_loc_6, _loc_3, _loc_4, _loc_5, param1[_loc_7 + 15], 10, -30611744);
                _loc_5 = md5_ii(_loc_5, _loc_6, _loc_3, _loc_4, param1[_loc_7 + 6], 15, -1560198380);
                _loc_4 = md5_ii(_loc_4, _loc_5, _loc_6, _loc_3, param1[_loc_7 + 13], 21, 1309151649);
                _loc_3 = md5_ii(_loc_3, _loc_4, _loc_5, _loc_6, param1[_loc_7 + 4], 6, -145523070);
                _loc_6 = md5_ii(_loc_6, _loc_3, _loc_4, _loc_5, param1[_loc_7 + 11], 10, -1120210379);
                _loc_5 = md5_ii(_loc_5, _loc_6, _loc_3, _loc_4, param1[_loc_7 + 2], 15, 718787259);
                _loc_4 = md5_ii(_loc_4, _loc_5, _loc_6, _loc_3, param1[_loc_7 + 9], 21, -343485551);
                _loc_3 = safe_add(_loc_3, _loc_8);
                _loc_4 = safe_add(_loc_4, _loc_9);
                _loc_5 = safe_add(_loc_5, _loc_10);
                _loc_6 = safe_add(_loc_6, _loc_11);
                _loc_7 = _loc_7 + 16;
            }
            return [_loc_3, _loc_4, _loc_5, _loc_6];
        }// end function

        public static function md5_cmn(param1:Number, param2:Number, param3:Number, param4:Number, param5:Number, param6:Number) : Number
        {
            return safe_add(bit_rol(safe_add(safe_add(param2, param1), safe_add(param4, param6)), param5), param3);
        }// end function

        public static function md5_ff(param1:Number, param2:Number, param3:Number, param4:Number, param5:Number, param6:Number, param7:Number) : Number
        {
            return md5_cmn(param2 & param3 | ~param2 & param4, param1, param2, param5, param6, param7);
        }// end function

        public static function md5_gg(param1:Number, param2:Number, param3:Number, param4:Number, param5:Number, param6:Number, param7:Number) : Number
        {
            return md5_cmn(param2 & param4 | param3 & ~param4, param1, param2, param5, param6, param7);
        }// end function

        public static function md5_hh(param1:Number, param2:Number, param3:Number, param4:Number, param5:Number, param6:Number, param7:Number) : Number
        {
            return md5_cmn(param2 ^ param3 ^ param4, param1, param2, param5, param6, param7);
        }// end function

        public static function md5_ii(param1:Number, param2:Number, param3:Number, param4:Number, param5:Number, param6:Number, param7:Number) : Number
        {
            return md5_cmn(param3 ^ (param2 | ~param4), param1, param2, param5, param6, param7);
        }// end function

        public static function safe_add(param1:Number, param2:Number) : Number
        {
            var _loc_3:* = (param1 & 65535) + (param2 & 65535);
            var _loc_4:* = (param1 >> 16) + (param2 >> 16) + (_loc_3 >> 16);
            return (param1 >> 16) + (param2 >> 16) + (_loc_3 >> 16) << 16 | _loc_3 & 65535;
        }// end function

        public static function bit_rol(param1:Number, param2:Number) : Number
        {
            return param1 << param2 | param1 >>> 32 - param2;
        }// end function

    }
```

Comment: You can't decrypt a hash.  Hashing is not encryption and more of a one way function that is non reversible.  Although MD5 is insecure and can be reversed the principle of hashing remains one way.

Comment: You can't, in short. In long, there are different inputs that produce the same MD5 hashes, as well as any other hashes, so you will be unable to distinguish between them.

Answer (score 6):

You can't decrypt a hash. Hashing is not encryption and more of a one way function that is non reversible. Although MD5 is insecure and can be reversed the principle of hashing remains one way.